# I want to import xml file into datagridview that head text already written

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kChVA.png)` 
I want to import xml file into datagridview that head text already written.

If I write header text and xml file, and press button that view the data of xml file, I want to see first image. However, When I press the button, I see the second image. Please let me know how to import xml file into datagridview seperately?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kChVA.png)

Comment: Why?  if you use datagridview1.DataSource = dt it will automatically add the header.  Trying to configure a DataGridView is complicated and using the datasource will simplify code.

Comment: Thank you, I want to load xml file data on datagridview header file. But I didn't find its solution.

Comment: I want to code header column with datagridview designer and data with xml files. But I don't know its solution.

Comment: Again why.  You can modify the datagridview after you load the data which is easier.

Comment: Because I received this homework. I think that it is solved by using xml.linq.

Comment: Notice the first character in the header.  One is a capital letter and the other lower case.  Which is correct?

Comment: Aha. it is my mistake. I'll update the image.

Comment: I want to insert data into the column 1,2, and 3. But in fact, the data is inserted in the Product_Id, Product_Name, and Product_price. I want to code header column with datagridview designer or linq, and data with xml files.